# Prometheus count metric - reset counter at the start time

Tags: prometheus

How can I get the real count metric in Prometheus?

Currently, count metric gives running information - like till now how many requests have hit a certain endpoint.

But I want numbers like from 9:00 AM to 5:00 PM on a certain day, how many times my endpoint got hit? Can it consider counter value as 0 at 9:00 AM and do the calculations?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Range Queries API with `start` and `end` timestamps:

Documentation: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/

```
query=<string>: Prometheus expression query string.
start=<rfc3339 | unix_timestamp>: Start timestamp.
end=<rfc3339 | unix_timestamp>: End timestamp.
step=<duration | float>: Query resolution step width in duration format or float number of seconds.
timeout=<duration>: Evaluation timeout. Optional. Defaults to and is capped by the value of the -query.timeout flag.
```

Comment: I am plotting this in Grafana.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the new `@` modifier https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/2.26/querying/basics/#modifier

I'd assume something like this works:

```
http_requests_total - (http_requests_total @ start())
```

They have a blog post about it: https://prometheus.io/blog/2021/02/18/introducing-the-@-modifier/